# Laravel sorting associative arrays

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to sort an array based on a specific key but it's not working. The array is below when in JSON format. I want to sort it in **ascending** order by **id_question**.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public function compare($ar1, $ar2){
  if ($ar1['id_question']<$ar2['id_question']) {
    return 1;
  }else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Call the sort function:

```
uasort($related, Array ($this, 'compare'));
```

This is what it returns:
[image]
[image]

### As you can see, it doesn't apply the sort.

**It's done
here is solution**

```
usort($related, function($a, $b){
  if ($a['id_question'] < $b['id_question']) {
   return -1;
  }else {
   return 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't post images of text.

Comment: Sorry Andreas!!

Comment: but if any one want to sort by question then it will not work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this helps -

```
$listItem = collect($related)->sortBy('id_question')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$related = collect($related)->sortBy('id_question')->all();
```

Comment: It is still not sorted. Please help :(